# Using two input fields to create Date object with computer property (getter and setter) Ember JS

Tags: date, time, ember.js, getter-setter, computed-properties

So I am using two inputs fields in html `{{date-picker value=activeFromDate placeholder='Date' popperContainer='#alerts-settings'}}` and `{{input value=activeFromTime type="time" placeholder='Time' id="appt" name="appt" class="time-picker"}}`.

One returns date in 10 digits and one returns time in this format, e.g.) "09:23".

I would like to use computed properties with custom getters/setters to create Date() object.

```
activeFromDate: computed('model.active_from', {
  get() {
    // If model.active_from currently exists and is a JavaScript Date object, extract the date number
    // from it to pass to the `date-picker` component
    if (this.get('model.active_from')) {
      return doSomethingToGetDateNumberFromTimestamp();
    }
  },
  set(key, value) {
    // When the `date-picker` component updates the value, create a new Date object in the alert model
    this.set('model.active_from', doSomethingToGetTimestampFromDateString());
    return value;
  }
}),

activeFromTime...,
```

`modal.active_from` is where date&time needs to be saved on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be best served by using moment for your time math needs. There's a convenient ember wrapper available here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-moment

The moment api will have methods for both of your needs